# How to set output precision to float in c

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

How to set a precision of mantissa in C? 
I want my program to print exactly 6 digits after the dot.

I tried using `%2.6le` to indicate that I want 6 digits, but then the program prints values like
`x=0.12345678...`
as `1.234567e-001`
instead of
`0.123456`

Every answer I see here is for C++, but not for C. Any help?

Comment: In `%2.6le`, the `l` length modifier is incorrect. Use `%.6e` for both `float` and `double`, and `%.6Le` for `long double`. (Change `e` to `f` to get the format you want.)

Answer (score 4):

Use `%.6f`. The `f` is for flat decimal point notation; your `e` is for scientific notation (i.e. mantissa times power of ten).

Comment: Thanks! It works like charm now. Again, for some insane reason this site does not allow me to upvote you.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation. You can accept his answer though. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra: Don't worry about it. I'm glad your problem is solved. Next time check the manuals first; there's plenty of documentation about `printf` available.